# Deactivating links in PHP

Tags: php

The below code has a link to apply for a job only when a deadline is not met.How can I make the link deactivate after the deadline for application has passed,or just change the link label from 'apply' to 'closed'?I will appreciate your help.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {

    $ref=$row['id'];

  echo "<tr id=".$ref.">";
   echo "<td >" .$row['refNo'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td >" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td >" . $row['positions'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['typeofContract']."</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['deadline'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" .$row['dept']."</td>";
   $det= $row['details'];

   echo "<td style='width:100px' >" ."<a href='../../admin/admin/jobdetails/".$det."' target='_blank'>Job details</a>" . "</td>";

   echo "<td>".'<a href="apply.php?deptid='.$ref.'" style="color:blue" >Apply</a>'."</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
```

Comment: What is in your `$row['deadline']` variable, some kind of date? Compare it to todays date and do something with that.

Comment: What does this have to do with JavaScript?

Comment: Do you want this `deactivation` to happen dynamically on the page as the date and time for deactivation is reached, or just when the page is loaded.

Comment: @RiggsFolly,I want it to happen dynamically on the page.Am not also conversant with cron jobs

Comment: cron jobs wont help with this. So you need to write some javascript that will do this dynamically on the page as the page sits in front of your user.

Comment: How is done with javascript @RiggsFolly ?Am new to js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if($row['deadline'] >= time()) echo "<td>".'<a href="apply.php?deptid='.$ref.'" style="color:blue" >Apply</a>'."</td>";
```

if your $row['deadline'] is a timestamp, this echo would only be fired if the timestamp is lower than the actual time. of course you can return any html in that case, for example:

```
 if($row['deadline'] >= time()) echo "<td>".'<a href="#" style="color:blue" >DEADLINE REACHED</a>'."</td>";
```

hope it helps

edit:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_time.asp

Comment: It has really helped.I was using CURDATE() but it failed.I have replaced it with time() function and it has worked.thanks @messerbill

Comment: This will not make the status change dynamically it will only happen when the user reloads the page AFTER the deadline has been passed.

Comment: yes this is true, but i think no user would stay longer than a few minutes on a page, so this is more practicable than to listen if a date broke the deadline all the time...

Comment: the issue is that it runs this code always run even when condition is wrong.any help?if($row['deadline'] < getdate()) {echo "<td>".'<a href="#" style="color:blue" >CLOSED</a>'."</td>";}

Comment: what format has $row['deadline']? please post some value of it

Comment: Also the dateline field is of type Date

Comment: so you have to convert it to timestamp before comparing with time() (what i have posted above). http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php

Comment: thanks for the link @messerbill.It has worked.I had to convert deadline to timestamp.